# Proving $\frac{n^2}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x^2_i} \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{x_i^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers with $x_i \neq 0$ for any index $i$. Also, suppose $\sum_{i} x_i \neq 0$. How can I show that the following equality holds?

$$\frac{n^2}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x^2_i} \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{x_i^2}$$

I've tried many things, but I've had no luck. In fact, I'm not even entirely sure if it holds anymore because I can't prove it, but I can't think of a counterexample either. I've looked at Cauchy Schwarz, etc. The numbers can be negative.

Comment: That is the inequality between harmonic anc arithmetic mean. Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3797373/42969

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i^2}\right) \geq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \cdot \frac{1}{x_i}\right)^2 = n^2
$$